# How to avoid Excel localizing object names and breaking macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this line of code in my macro:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
```

When I open the file and run the macro on a non-English version of Excel, this code breaks. For example on the Japanese system I tested it on, I would need to change the previous line to:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("グラフ 6").Activate
```

(グラフ means Chart in Japanese)

This seems ridiculous as these are object names, not meant to be human readable anyway but used to identify objects. Is there any way of it working whatever the language of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these names are used for programming purposes, but these names are also visible to the user, so it is an interesting issue... To solve it, you can simply refer to the Chart by it's integer index value.

For example, instead of:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
```

You could use:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(6).Activate
```

In the above, I assumed that "Chart 6" is indexed by the value 6, but it can really be any number. For example, if you've created and destroyed five previous charts, and this chart is now the only chart on the worksheet, the chart named "Chart 6" would actually be indexed by the integer value one (1).

So you will have to figure out which index number your chart corresponds to, and then use that index value in your code.

Make sense?

**Update: Reply to Laurent**

> As for the name being displayed to the
>   user, what if I named the graph
>   "Motorboat"?

That's it! That's your answer!!

I was about to suggest that you stick to the portion of the name that does not change. For example, "Chart 6" is being changed to "グラフ 6". So, in this case, you should simply loop through all the charts looking for the one that ends in the name "6". But, even better, is to simply avoid words that will be automatically translated. So, instead of naming it, "Chart 6", name it, yes, "Motorboat" or anything else that would not be automatically translated.

Using this approach, instead of:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
```

You would use:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Motorboat").Activate
```

Agreed that this is not ideal. There might even be a programmatic code name for charts that I'm not aware of, which, if it exists, would allow you to use any name you want. But, in the absence of such a feature, then using a name for your chart that would not be translated seems to be the best and easiest way to go.

Hope this helps!

Mike

Comment: The problem is, "Chart 6" refers to *that* graph. Charts(6) refers to just any graph which happens to be 6th in the list and this can change over time, so I can't use that. Even if I determine the correct index, it could change, and I'll be modifying a different graph, so that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As for the name being displayed to the user, what if I named the graph "Motorboat"? Would Excel have to use some sort of dictionary to translate "Motorboat" into Japanese when the file is opened on a Japanese PC? Souds a bit ridiculous. So just because I happen to name it "Graph", I don't see why it should in that particular case either. If I name my graph some way, that name is independant of the language.

Comment: @Laurent: "Even if I determine the correct index, it could change, and I'll be modifying a different graph, so that doesn't solve the problem". Well, it's rare that a workbook is that dynamic. You can usually determine that it's #6 and then lock down your code. That said, you are 100% correct: it *can* change, so this suggestion is not universal -- you would have to change your reference numbers if you ever added or deleted a chart. This could be done more easily by using global constants for each chart number, instead of hard-coded numbers. But, agreed, this is not ideal if making changes.

Comment: @Laurent: "As for the name being displayed to the user, what if I named the graph 'Motorboat'?" I agree with you, I think that the existing behavior is a mistake. But I understand the intent: I've seen a Dutch installation of Excel where "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc. was translated to "Blad1", "Blad2", etc. I believe that this was helpful to the user. But from a programmatic point of view, it's a big problem. For sheets, one can utilize the code name: 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', etc., which will never change. But I don't know of any equivalent for Charts.

Comment: @Laurent: "As for the name being displayed to the user, what if I named the graph 'Motorboat'?" Actually, wait a minute... That's the answer!! See my updated reply, above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to call the objects in such a way that you reference the *objects themselves* and not by referencing the objects via their respective textual names.

One thing that's helped me in cases like this is to use `For Each` to iterate through a collection of objects.  Such as:

```
Sub DoSomethingWillAllChartObjects()

Dim cs As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    For Each cs In ws.ChartObjects
        Debug.Print cs.Name, cs.Index

    Next cs
Next ws

End Sub
```

The above code iterates through all charts in all worksheets in the given workbook and allows you to do something to those objects.  You don't need to know the name of the chart to do something with that code.

Perhaps what you might do is use `For Each` to iterate through all items and then add some `If ... Then` logic to test to see if a particular `ChartObject` requires action in your code.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem of identifying one particular graph which I want to modify. Using your solution, the If condition would have to identify just one graph, and what better way of doing that than using its name?

Comment: I would ask the question, "how do you know the name?".  If you happen to simply know the name of the object and if all of the names of the charts end with an arabic numeral (0-9), you could at least parse through all of the charts while checking the end of the chart names to see if it matches.  That's not the ideal solution, but I'm not sure how else you would do it since you're trying to reference the object by name.

On another note, if you only have one chart per worksheet, use the code I provided but only for a single worksheet.